# How to change the sprite of an object from another's script?

Tags: sprites, game-maker

I have an object A and an object B, I want that when object B is in a certain position, the sprite of object A changes to that corresponding to that position, how do I change the sprite of object A from the script of object b?

The image may give them an idea of what I want to do, object B is the glove, And the object A is the viewer.

Tansk form any help.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If you have only one instance of the object A then you can use `with` statement or object's name:

```
with objA
{
    sprite_index = YourSprite;
}
```

or

```
objA.sprite_index = YourSprite;
```

It won't work when you have more than one instance of the object A (then all instances will be changed). In this case you can use the name of the instance (press RMB on the instance in the room editor and select `Copy Instance Name` (also you can rename it). Then code will be like this:

```
inst_FD70AA4D.sprite_index = YourSprite;
```

or

```
inst_YourName.sprite_index = YourSprite;
```

There are couple examples:

[using instance's creation code](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/78963719/stackoverflow/gml/hero_select_1.gmk) (if you don't understand what it is, check the [documentation](http://docs.yoyogames.com/source/dadiospice/001_advanced%20use/more%20about%20rooms/index.html) (see `Creation Code`).

[using automatic creation](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/78963719/stackoverflow/gml/hero_select_2.gmk)

I made it lot time ago in GM8, you can just import them to GMS.